# How to fix problem regarding selecting row by condition from pandas

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements

I know how to select row by specific condition as below.

`df[df['col'] == 'example']`

But I am very confusing when I use this syntax after using `read_excel()` and `melt()`.

Following is my example and I've trouble in figuring out why it happen.

Correct works :

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'term' : ['mid term',' final'],
                     '20230001' : ['A+','A0'], 
                     '20030002' : ['B-', 'B+'], 
                     '20030003' : ['A-','A-']})
test2 = pd.melt(test, id_vars=['term'], value_name = 'score')

test2.dtypes
# Out[138]: 
# term        object
# variable    object
# score       object
# dtype: object

test2[test2['variable'] == '20230001']
# Out[141]: 
#       term  variable score
# 0  mid term  20230001    A+
# 1     final  20230001    A0
```

Something wrong :

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\test.xlsx')   # test.xlsx is same data as test

df
#        term 20230001 20230002 20230003
# 0  mid term       A+       B-       A-
# 1     final       A0       B+       A-

df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['term'], value_name = 'score')

df2.dtypes
# Out[145]: 
# term        object
# variable    object
# score       object
# dtype: object

df2[df2['variable'] == '20230001']
# Out[146]: 
# Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [term, variable, score]
# Index: []

########## Not working well ###########
########## But it works well when I deal 'variable' as numeric ##########

df2[df2['variable'] == 20230001]
# Out[147]: 
#        term  variable score
# 0  mid term  20230001    A+
# 1     final  20230001    A0
```

Comment: What is the issue? If you want the column to be a string, you can simply do `df2["variable"] = df2["variable"].astype(str)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code must work. I suspect you have spaces in `df2['variable']` values. Try this line. `strip` removes spaces from the start and end of strings:

```
df2[df2['variable'].str.strip()== '20230001']
```

Comment: I didn't work. I did it on my home PC and office PC, but both failed. 
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!" I think 'Variables' read as numeric not string even `dtypes` show it as 'object'

Comment: Your codes above are identical except that in the first one you are making the data and in the second one you are importing some data. So, the imported data is not exactly how you think it is. Please upload that data so I can take a look

Comment: Sorry I've no idea how to upload data.  This is why I create very quite simple example table in Excel.